# Perfective forms of видеть - завидеть и увидеть

Tags: глаголы

As the title states, what is the difference between the two perfective forms of the verb видеть? Essentially, I am asking:

> When would you use завидеть and when would you use увидеть?

To give you an example of where I am trying to use it is in a message stating:

> I do not know, if you will see this message.

What I have so far:

> Я не знаю, если вы завидите/увидите это письмо.

Comment: There is no word `завидеть`. You could easily discover it by examining dictionaries.  -1 for the question.

Comment: Pray tell me, what is this then? [завидеть](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/завидеть#Russian) and [увидеть](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/увидеть#Russian). Additionally, another one for you: [завидеть](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=%E7%E0%E2%E8%E4%E5%F2%FC&l1=1). Are you satisfied? @user31264

Comment: Ok, there is such a word, which is so rare that I didn't know it.  In ruscorpora.ru it is about two orders of magnitude less frequent than увидеть.  Still, you should only use увидеть.

Comment: Значение слова Завидеть по Ефремовой:
Завидеть - Заметить издали

Comment: @MrMarley, also if you will say `завидеть` to most native russian speakers they would think that you're talking about [`envy`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).

Comment: @user28434, incredible! The noun, `_зависть_`, looks extremely similar to a verb.

Comment: @MrMarley, is `incredible` part sarcasm? But anyways two words semantically different, but etymologically related, like english words `vision`(from *lat* video) and `envy` (from *lat* invidia).

Comment: @user28434, no it is not. I'm just discovering the nuances of the language, and they are far greater than I anticipated. This is the first noun I have come across that looks like a verb. I've have seen the nouns that look like adjectives - the first one that comes to mind is `ванная`. My Russian teacher was not joking when she said, "There are so many irregularities in Russian, that you can no longer refer to them as irregularities. They just exist in the language, and you will need to learn them."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Увидеть** means just **to see**. This word is frequently used in different situations.

> Вчера я увидел его на вокзале.

**Завидеть** means **to nofice from the distance**. The verb is used mostly in the form of **деепричастие**(завидев, завидя)

> Не боясь его, стрекотали в густой траве кузнечики, летали бабочки, ящерицы сидели на тёплых камнях и грелись и, **завидев** Колюнчика, исчезали в траве. [Алексей Варламов. Купавна // «Новый Мир», 2000] …→
>
> Павел стоял в коридоре у окна и, **завидев** меня, неприветливо поморщился, немного согнувшись при этом в поясе ― будто хотел встретить гостя поклоном. [Андрей Волос. Недвижимость (2000) // «Новый Мир», 2001]

There are lots of examples in the national corpus.

> Я не знаю, увидите ли вы это письмо.
> This will be correct.

Answer (score 3):

`Завидеть` seems to be an obsolete and colloquial (perhaps) word. This word appears in dictionaries, but usually is not used in modern speech. This can be translated as `to see something from afar`.

I think you want say `Я не знаю, увидишь ли ты это письмо`.

Answer (score 2):

Завидеть is (practically?) never used as a verb, but you can meet its adverbial participle завидев, mostly in texts.

Answer (score 0):

Завидеть - to see from or at a great distance. It's a very rarely used word.

*Он убежа́л, завидев полице́йского. - He ran away at the sight of the policeman.*

source: https://en.openrussian.org/ru/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. It seems you're associated with this site. You need to declare that in your post; see [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).